# Javascript Array.splice stopped working correctly in my Angular project

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, splice

I was working on a project in Angular 4 and needed to batch through an array of ids.  I would send the removed items to an Observable function, and when the subscription returned I would check the remaining array before looping the batch.

The first time I did this it worked perfectly, the original array was reduced over time to zero items.  The second time I did this it no longer worked.  Every time the subscription returns the original array was suddenly full again.

The original array was an element of the component that was making the subscription.

```
RemoveItemsArray : Array<number>;
```

I had an event handler function initializing the values and calling the batch function.

```
HandleActions( action, payload )
{
    switch( action )
    {
        case “finish”:
            DoSomething();
            break;
        case “remove”:
            this.RemoveItemsArray = payload.items;
            this.ProcessRemoveItems();
            break;
    }
}
```

The Batching function would console log the array being correctly sized before the API function was called.  Then in the response suddenly all the items were back and therefore it became an infinite loop.

```
ProcessRemoveItems()
{
    let executeItems = this.RemoveItemsArray.splice(0, 10);
    this.service.RemoveItemsAPI( executeItems )
        .subscribe ( response =>  {
            if( response.StatusCode == 200 )
            {
                if( this.RemoveItemsArray.length > 0 )
                {
                    this.ProcessRemoveItems();
                }
                else
                {
                    this.HandleAction(“finish”,null);
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: This is dangerous code for sure. If ever `HandleActions` is called before the array is drained your data will get overwritten. You might have other code that could be modifying the array as well. You should make a copy of the array and pass it to `ProcessRemoveItems()`. Otherwise you'll need a mechanism to ensure the array is not modified while consuming it. Keep in mind `this.RemoveItemsArray = payload.items;` simply points to `payload.items`. So modifying `payload.items` is the same as modifying `this.RemoveItemsArray`.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're modifying the array elsewhere in the middle of draining it.

You'll want to make a copy of the array if this is the case. I can't tell from the given code what modifications are being made, so all I can do is give you a couple guesses.

**Solution 1: Copy `payload.items` to `RemoveItemsArray`.**

**This assumes `RemoveItemsArray` is not modifed during draining**

```js
HandleActions( action, payload )
{
    switch( action )
    {
        case “finish”:
            DoSomething();
            break;
        case “remove”:
            this.RemoveItemsArray = [...payload.items];
            this.ProcessRemoveItems();
            break;
    }
}
```

**Solution 2: Pass an all new array to `ProcessRemoveItems`**

```js
HandleActions( action, payload )
{
    switch( action )
    {
        case “finish”:
            DoSomething();
            break;
        case “remove”:
            this.RemoveItemsArray = payload.items;
            this.ProcessRemoveItems([...payload.items]);
            break;
    }
}

ProcessRemoveItems(items)
{
    let executeItems = items.splice(0, 10);
    this.service.RemoveItemsAPI( executeItems )
        .subscribe ( response =>  {
            if( response.StatusCode == 200 )
            {
                if( items.length > 0 )
                {
                    this.ProcessRemoveItems(items);
                }
                else
                {
                    this.HandleAction(“finish”,null);
                }
            }
        });
}
```